# Test Driven Development - Testing input parameter when using TypeScript

Tags: typescript, jestjs, tdd, ts-jest

I'm getting started with TDD and was wondering if I need to test input parameters in a TypeScript environment?

For example, I have a function which takes a string, and parses json if it's valid

```js
export const tryParseJSON = (jsonString: string) => {
  if (jsonString) {
    try {
      const o = JSON.parse(jsonString);

      // Handle non-exception-throwing cases:
      // Neither JSON.parse(false) or JSON.parse(1234) throw errors, hence the type-checking,
      // but... JSON.parse(null) returns null, and typeof null === "object",
      // so we must check for that, too. Thankfully, null is falsey, so this suffices:
      if (o && typeof o === 'object') {
        return o;
      }
    } catch (e) {}
  }

  return false;
};
```

I wrote the following tests for it:

```js
describe('Helper Function tryParseJSON', () => {
  it('should return false if input parameter is a string', async () => {
    expect(tryParseJSON('1234')).toEqual(false);
  });
  it('should return false if input parameter is null', async () => {
    expect(tryParseJSON(null)).toEqual(false);
  });
  it('should return false if input parameter is false', async () => {
    expect(tryParseJSON(false)).toEqual(false);
  });
  it('should return true if input parameter is valid JSON', async () => {
    const jsonString = JSON.stringify({ test: 'testing' });
    expect(tryParseJSON(jsonString)).toEqual({ test: 'testing' });
  });
});
```

However, since I use "ts-jest" which uses type checking, the tests don't run because `null` and `false` are no strings.

Now, the question is whether it's good practice to deactivate type-checking (only in ts-jest, not TypeScript itself) and write those types of tests, or whether the typescript compiler is good enough?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're ignoring the compiler type checks then...why are you using TypeScript? Ideally it's to *avoid* passing the wrong data type. If you throw that away, you're left with very little of actual use in TS - it's a fancy transpiler. It's like buying a car in order to hammer nails.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I meant to disable type checking in ts-jest, so I can pass types to the test functions which I usually couldn't do. That's exactly why I'm asking this question. If TypeScript prevents me from passing the wrong types, there should be no need to write tests for it. Edited the Question to clarify.

Comment: Yes, it does stop you. Well, at compiler level. If you bypass the compiler with assertions, you can pass any value to the function but in most cases you *shouldn't* be using type assertions. And if you do, you must be absolutely sure it's OK. If you follow that, then you shouldn't run into a situation where a function expects one type but receives another.

Comment: Okay cool, thanks for the comment. So are you saying that if I don't bypass the compiler while developing, there is no need to write test cases, checking wrong input parameters?

Comment: Yes, this is pretty much the central point of TypeScript - providing type safety.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the quick reply!